# invalid json format with double quotes

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs

I am working on a angularjs application which is getting data from an external source. I tried to process data using JSON.stringify but
 JSON.Stringify resulted in the format below which is not the correct format expected by my application.

```
[{ "CenterName": null, "CenterId": "0", "Name": null, "text": "Operations",items: [{ "text": "Aruba" }, { "text": "Anguilla" }, { "text": "Argentina" }]}];
```

How can I remove double quotes that enclose each parent item?

```
 [{ CenterName: null, CenterId: 0, Name: null, text: "Operations",items: [{ text: "Aruba" }, { text: "Anguilla" }, { text: "Argentina" }]}];
```

Comment: The property names need the quotation marks, otherwise it's not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try javascript regex replace
i.e.

```
var originalString = '[{ "CenterName": null, "CenterId": "0", "Name": null, "text": "Operations",items: [{ "text": "Aruba" }, { "text": "Anguilla" }, { "text": "Argentina" }]}]';

var txt = originalString.replace(/"(\w+)":/gi,"$1:");
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert JSON to an object you can use this:

`angular.fromJson(jsonString)`

Documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson